# How to give API read / write permission for an added application in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When calling an API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/publicipaddresses/list to get List IP Addresses through a postman I'm getting the following error :

{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'acc04996-6ca3-4a2f-ba94-xxxx' with object id 'acc04996-6ca3-4a2f-ba94-xxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read' over scope '/subscriptions/a530d6ae-6e7f-4c74-89fb-97273a63f8cd/resourceGroups/nag_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Network' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

**Please let me know how to grant permission so that I can call all the API's through Postman. Thanks**

Comment: How are you getting the authorization token?

Comment: I'm generating the token in Postman. By using the following URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenent-id}}/oauth2/token

Comment: Without digging into documentation,  I'm not in front of a computer, I believe I've done this with a service principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means your client app does not have the permission to do the `Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read` action.

To fix the issue, just navigate to the subscription or the resource group `nag_resource_group` in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for your client app name and add it as a role e.g. `Contributor`, `Virtual Machine Contributor`.

[image]

If you don't want the built-in roles, you can also [create a custom RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles), just include the `Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read` action in its [`Actions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles#custom-role-example). If you are not familar with Azure RBAC roles, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview).